# Difference between the two methods of creating class objects in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I'm learning JSP
Recently I came across two methods of creating class object in JSP

Method 1:

```
<jsp:useBean id = "obj" class = "ClassName" />
<%
 obj.method();
%>
```

Method 2:

```
<%
 ClassName obj = new ClassName();
 obj.method();
%>
```

- Can any one please explain what exactly is the difference?
- Which is a good practice?
- In which context Method 1/Method 2 is relevant and where it is not

Thank you in advance

Comment: The first approach doesn't *create* a new object at all - and won't work unless there's already a variable called `obj`. The two situations aren't comparable.

Comment: In Method 1: what is the reference of obj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

The `<jsp:useBean>` is a standard action element used to locate or instantiate a JavaBean component. Firstly `<jsp: useBean>` tries to locate an instance of the Bean class if found its fine, if not then it will instantiate it from a class mentioned in the `class` attribute. By default it will look for the object in page scope if `scope` attribute is not specified.The name of the bean is same as we have given in `id` attribute of `<jsp:useBean>`. If the object reference doesn't exist with the name we have specify  then it will create a instance and find the scope of the variable, `class` attributes defines the bean class and `type` attribute defines the parent class or interface of the Bean class.

You can access the bean style properties of the Java bean using `<jsp:useBean>`:

```
<jsp:useBean id = "obj" class = "ClassName" />
<jsp:getProperty name="obj" property="someProperty"/>
```

The above code looks for a Java bean stored as `obj` in `page`, if it doesn't finds one tries to create a new bean using the class definition specified by the `class` attribute and sets the newly created bean to `page` scope. You try to access the `someProperty` attribute of the `obj` bean . The `someProperty` attribute should have a bean style getter. Go through the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnair.html) for more.

**Method 2 :**

You are creating a local object within the `service()` method of the generated Servlet. You are not setting it to any scope.

**Note:**

Scriptlets and `<jsp:useBean>` are not advisable . Please use JSTL and EL expressions.

Answer (score 0):

`<jsp:useBean>` tag allows you to define the [scope of the bean](http://profesores.elo.utfsm.cl/~agv/elo330/2s03/projects/Tomcat/doc/1.2/syntaxref1217.html), while in latter

the scope of `obj` is local to `jspService()` generated method

Answer (score 0):

In Method 1: You should represent method as:

```
<jsp:useBean id = "obj" class = "ClassName" />
${obj.method()}
```

Then it will be good practice than Method 2.

Answer (score 0):

Rather create objects in controller (servlet or portlet) and then use EL and JSTL to render view (JSP). Dont use scriptlets (<% %>) if possible.

I guess method 1 is static method of class ClassName.